# Not able to access the account Id from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

Below is the JSON stringified response. I tried to access the account ( `data.fields.Account`) but I am getting an `undefined error` for data.

Fields itself:

```
{
  "data": {
    "apiName": "Contact",
    "childRelationships": {},
    "fields": {
      "Account": {
        "displayValue": "tesss",
        "value": {
          "apiName": "Account",
          "childRelationships": {},
          "fields": {
            "Id": {
              "displayValue": null,
              "value": "0016F00003Oaze0QAB"
            }
          },
          "id": "0016F00003Oaze0QAB",
          "lastModifiedById": "0056F00000BWFeNQAX",
          "lastModifiedDate": "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z",
          "recordTypeInfo": null,
          "systemModstamp": "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "0036F00003MoKW9QAN",
    "lastModifiedById": "0056F00000BWFeNQAX",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z",
    "recordTypeInfo": null,
    "systemModstamp": "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us more code, how are you accessing this field?

Comment: `console.log(data.fields.Account.value.fields)` .Try this its working

Comment: I have tried the same . I am getting below error    [Cannot read property 'Account' of undefined]

Comment: I have tried data.fields itself getting undefind

Comment: did you parse this JSON object before accessing?

Comment: No I have not done anything..above response I posted is the stringified result.

Comment: Please share some, how you are trying  to access that object

Comment: window.console.log('this is data'+data);
 window.console.log('this is stringified result'+JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: this is data[object Object]

Comment: this is stringified result{"data":{"apiName":"Contact","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Account":{"displayValue":"tesss","value":{"apiName":"Account","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0016F00003Oaze0QAB"}},"id":"0016F00003Oaze0QAB","lastModifiedById":"0056F00000BWFeNQAX","lastModifiedDate":"2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z","recordTypeInfo":null,"systemModstamp":"2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z"}}},"id":"0036F00003MoKW9QAN","lastModifiedById":"0056F00000BWFeNQAX","lastModifiedDate":"2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z","recordTypeInfo":null}}

Comment: above 2 are console logs and respect outputs

Comment: Please post the code ,you are trying

Comment: Do you retrieve this information through an asynchronous function? Maybe the first time you are accessing this field it is undefined, try checking if undefined first.

Comment: @DiegoRosales Why then wouldn't the error read `Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It will helps you.

```js
var data = {
   data: {
      apiName: "Contact",
      childRelationships: {},
      fields: {
        Account: {
          displayValue: "tesss",
          value: {
            apiName: "Account",
            childRelationships: {},
            fields: {
              Id: {
                displayValue: null,
                value: "0016F00003Oaze0QAB"
              }
            },
            id: "0016F00003Oaze0QAB",
            lastModifiedById: "0056F00000BWFeNQAX",
            lastModifiedDate: "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z",
            recordTypeInfo: null,
            systemModstamp: "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z"
          }
        }
      },
      id: "0036F00003MoKW9QAN",
      lastModifiedById: "0056F00000BWFeNQAX",
      lastModifiedDate: "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z",
      recordTypeInfo: null,
      systemModstamp: "2019-11-15T18:28:51.000Z"
    }
}
console.log("Id==============",data.data.fields.Account.value.id);
```